# how to add data into table wp_posts in wordpress in adding new column?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add new column in table `wp_posts` and insert data into this field. Please have to solve it for me. Because I don't know why I cannot insert into this field.

Answer (score 2):

use `add post meta`

```
add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
```

retrieve post meta value

```
get_metadata('post', $post_id, $key, $single);
```