# how can i add one column in table wp_post in wordpress and add data into column?

Tags: php, wordpress

> I want to add field resume_code into table posts in wordpress and add
>   data into this field. now i have add a field call 'resume_code'
>   already. but i cannot add data into this field. please help me to
>   solve.

EDIT:

```
 $post_information = array(
            'ID'             => $current_post,
            'post_title'     => $_POST['fullName'],
            'post_content'   => strip_tags($_POST['postContent']),
            'post_type'      => 'resume',
            'comment_status' => 'open',
            'ping_status'    => 'open',
            'post_status'    => 'publish'
            'resume_code'    => $_GET['resume']
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
```

Comment: Include your code in your question.

Comment: Why you want to ruined wp_posts table ? there are various other solution. Custom Fields etc..

Comment: Yeah, create a metabox and add your field there, and then just pull it out using either `get_post_meta()` or `get_post_custom()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add data into table wp\_posts in wordpress in adding new column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758308/how-to-add-data-into-table-wp-posts-in-wordpress-in-adding-new-column)